# updating a mermaid diagram using mermaid.render throws promise undefined error

Tags: mermaid

I am getting an error when trying to update a mermaid js diagram. My understanding is that mermaid.render will create svg code the svg code is supposed to be passed to the callback.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is undefined

```html
<script type="module">
  import  mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
window.mermaid=mermaid;

setTimeout(updateMermaid,5000);

function after(svg){
        document.getElementById("mermaidflow").innerHTML = svg;
}

function updateMermaid(){
    console.log(mermaid);
    mermaidtext=document.getElementById("mermaidtext").value;
    console.log(mermaidtext);

    mermaid.render('mermaidflow',mermaidtext,after);
   
}
</script><textarea id="mermaidtext" > graph TD
     A --> B 
</textarea><br>
<input type=button value=updateMermaid onClick=updateMermaid()>

  <div id="mermaidflow" class="mermaid" style="max-width:800px">
    graph TD
    Start --> Stop 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use the id of the div 'mermaidflow' and not that of the textarea.  Also I don't think that your  tag is closed, which also might cause some problems.